# How to update WebDriverAgent (WDA) in MAC?

Tags: appium

I want to update WDA in my MAC machine, I tried to search few threads but didn't get my answer. How can i see the version of WDA running from my machine?

Could someone please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it as far as I know:

2. Reinstall your appium server, that will install the latest version of WDA as well.
3. Clone the WDA repository from here: https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent and pull all changes using git.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Andric , I can update appium by re installing appium server.

> npm -g uninstall appium

then

> npm -g install appium